# CMake syntax highlighting not working as expected

Tags: syntax-highlighting, plugin-cmake.vim, filetype-cmake

For most files, Vim (terminal) is syntax highlighting properly without any issues. However, I am unable to get it to work for `CMakeLists.txt`:

[image]

Neovim has no trouble with syntax highlighting, neither does gvim. I also tried this plugin with no effect: https://github.com/pboettch/vim-cmake-syntax

I have the following in my `.vimrc`

```
filetype plugin indent on
syntax on
set t_Co=256
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.cmake,CMakeLists.txt set filetype=cmake
# tried this variation too
# autocmd BufEnter *.cmake,CMakeLists.txt,*.cmake.in :setlocal filetype=cmake
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue it turns out is a conflict with the *Rainbow Parenthesis* plugin: https://github.com/kien/rainbow_parentheses.vim, which is too bad as it's a nice plugin but the syntax highlighting functionality is more important.

For future reference, the following variant of the *Rainbow Parenthesis* plugin is also problematic: https://github.com/luochen1990/rainbow

Comment: both times the same plugin?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/luochen1990/rainbow/issues/77

If using https://github.com/luochen1990/rainbow, we can turn it off for cmake language.

> A workaround (as @luochen1990 already noted): Disable the rainbow plugin for CMake files.

```
let g:rainbow_conf = {
\   'separately': {
\       'cmake': 0,
\   }
\}
```

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!